# RSS feed without Styling

Tags: feeds

I have a Drupal 7 webiste. I want RSS feed from a few views in my Drupal webiste.
I am able to get the feed but the .xml file has a lot of CSS styling in the description tag which is causing me some issues in the RSS reader.
I want to get rid of the CSS styling in the description tag.
Can anyone help ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'CSS styling'? Do you mean your body markup has inline styles? If so, you just need to create a new filter format, change it to plain text, and use that as the formatter for the description in the rss feed

Comment: By CSS Styling I mean CSS tags that are present inside the .XML file of the RSS feed . I want to get rid of all the CSS Styling that appears in the description tag.

Comment: Solution is the same - but why do you have `<style>` tags in a node body anyway?

Comment: I have no idea. When I had a look at the .xml file of my feed I could see the Styling in the description tag . I shall try your solution . Thank you verymuch

Answer (score 0):

you can copy views-view-row-rss.tpl.php to your theme folder 
and then

```
<description><?php print $description; ?></description>
```

replace with

```
<description><?php print preg_replace("/<style\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/style>/s", "", $description); ?></description>
```

it will remove css

if you also have inline styles then you need this

```
<?php $description = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1',$description); ?>
<description><?php print preg_replace("/<style\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/style>/s", "", $description); ?></description>
```